# Gravity Forms - Custom submissions?

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

I don't want to use the output that Gravity Forms has and would like to create my own form, but still use its back-end for entries, the field creations, etc..

I can do everything so far but the entry submission. I've looked and looked, without any luck. Is there a way to create an entry in Gravity Forms? Some class function?

Comment: Not sure if this is any use but may be something here. http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs

Comment: When you say 'create an entry in Gravity Forms' Do you mean just get it in to the db? I don't _think_ there is a built in function or class for that but you also want to use the the GF backend for field creations . . . would you get what you're looking if you just let GF do the work and modify the output with CSS? That's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way to get this done is to create a placeholder page, embed the form, and then use JavaScript to create an iframe and submit the form within.

Some sample code:

```
app.controller 'SubmitForm', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$filter', ($scope, $timeout, $filter) ->
    $scope.data = {}
    $scope.loading = $scope.thanks = false

    $scope.submit = ->
        $scope.loading = true

        $frame = $('<iframe/>', {
            id: '#dynamicGF'
            src: "/form-placeholder-page/?#{$filter('obj2url')($scope.data)}"

            load: ->
                $frame.contents().find('form [type=submit]:first').click()

                $timeout ->
                    $scope.$apply ->
                        $scope.loading = false
                        $scope.thanks = true

                    $frame.remove()
                , 175
        });

        $frame.css
            width: 0
            height: 0
            visibility: 'hidden'

        $frame.appendTo $('body')
        @
]
```